# C++ XML to C++ Object Mapping library?

Tags: c++

Is there any good automatic xml to C++ object library ?

With good benchmark and Multi - Platform support (if not at-least linux )

Edit :
More Description

I want to library like 
http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/
where I can use any xml as c++ object.

```
XMLOBJECT x=new XMLOBJECT("my.xml");

x->root
x->root->child
```

Means  XML Data Binding in C++

Comment: Note that to do that you need to preprocess the XSD for your XML types to C++ classes. You cannot throw arbitrary XML at this and expect to code for it. This is because C++ does not support dynamic class generation. It's a statically compiled language.

Comment: @Macke yes I will be having XSD for each xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you refer to what is called [XML Data Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_data_binding).

[gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) is a free tool that does it. There are of course many commercial tools - XML Spy and others. [Here](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDataBinding.htm) is a nice list of resources.

Answer (score 2):

boost::serialization provides that functionality, you can serialize your object to xml and back as well as to the other formats.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like [pococapsule](http://code.google.com/p/pococapsule/)

Answer (score 1):

We use [Codalogic LMX](http://www.codalogic.com/lmx/); a bit expensive, but they have a free "express" edition that might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [this lib](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/). It's multi-platform

Answer (score 0):

There are many. Please see some of them

- LibXML - http://xmlsoft.org/python.html
- Tiny XML -    http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/
- Rapid XML - http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/
- Code Synthesis XSD - http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/
- Applied mathematics - http://www.applied-mathematics.net/tools/xmlParser.html
- Xerces-C++ - http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/
- gSOAP - http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2/
- pugiXML - http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/
- XML Lite (Windows) - 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx

Comment: do all of them do data binding, or some are just for xml parsing?

Comment: Some are just for parsing. TinyXML for example.